# canvas getContext("2d") returns null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've tried this a few different ways, but I keep getting stuck with the same error. I've loaded an image to canvas before, but since I updated Safari a few days ago, I'm getting errors.

I'll post what I have at the moment, but I've tried doing it with jQuery, html's onLoad property, etc.

```
var cvs, ctx, img;
function init() {
   cvs = document.getElementById("profilecanvas");
   ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); /* Error in getContext("2d") */
   img = document.getElementById("profileImg");
   drawImg();
}

function drawImg() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.onload = init();
```

The IDs are correct and correspond to appropriate canvas and img tags. However, I keep getting `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'cvs.getContext')` and it doesn't seem to be getting any further. I'm sure it's some ID10T error, but I'm hoping someone can give me a clue as to what's causing this? Thank you.

Edit:
Okay, so this seems to work using `<body onload="init()">` now. However, it only displays occasionally, and if I try to run `init()` off of `$(document).ready()` or `document.onload` I still have no luck, and receive the error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you do this:

```
window.onload = init();
```

the function `init()` will be executed immediately (what causes the error, because `getContext()` gets called too early, i.e. before the DOM is loaded), and the return value of `init()` will be stored to `window.onload`.

So you want to actually do this:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Note the missing `()`.

Comment: I have the same problem as @stslavik, in Safari as well. I can't seem to get it working; even without init method or different approach, always have problems with context being null. Any thoughts? :/

Answer (score 136):

For others who hit this page while searching for [`getContext`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) returning null, it can happen if you have already requested a different type of context.

For example:

```
var canvas = ...;
var ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ctx3d = canvas.getContext('webgl'); // will always be null
```

The same is equally true if you reverse the order of calls.

Comment: So what can I do to get the context after I already requested a different type of context?

Comment: @TSR, I have the feeling it's not possible, but I'm not an authority. This might be helpful: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-element

Comment: If you need to display both 2D and 3D in the canvas, consider stacking two canvas elements, and making the topmost have a transparent background.

Comment: Thanks, so many other threads did not have this answer.  I am using JeeLiz Face Filters library and it is in fact using WebGL where as I was using filters with getContext("2d")

Comment: As I thought, for everyone with the same follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293778/switch-canvas-context (answer so far: no you can not)

Answer (score 25):

This has nothing to do with actual question, but since this question is first result when googling `getContex("2d") null` I'm adding the solution to problem I had:

Make sure that you use `getContext("2d")` and not `getContext("2D")` - notice the lower-case **d**.

Answer (score 9):

Just put your JavaScript at the end of the page it will ... put an end to your problems... i tried everything but this the most logical and simple solution.. as that JS will run only after the other part(ie the upper page) has loaded.. hope this help

Comment: This is one of the basic practices that one can so in order to achieve error free JS. and it works .. so who so ever has voted a -1 plz reconsider ur stand or at least comment on it... correct me if u can

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I suspect the downvoter's reason was that while your problem is a best practice (in some cases) the question included a specific bug that would not be solved by this suggestion.  In other words, it may be well meant advice but it's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Worked, but still need to understand in what cases its not working.

Answer (score 9):

It should be noted that the context is not always `2d`. All possible values that I'm aware of:

```js
'2d'
'webgl'
'webgl2'
'experimental-webgl'
'bitmaprenderer'
```

MDN `getContext()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#parameters

*From the MDN doc above:*

#### Return value

A rendering context which is either

- [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) for `2d`
- [WebGLRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext) for `webgl` and `experimental-webgl`
- [WebGL2RenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext) for `webgl2`
- [ImageBitmapRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext) for `bitmaprenderer`

If the contextType doesn't match a possible drawing context, or differs from the first contextType requested, `null` is returned.

Comment: and how can I know which is the right context without trying all of them? (and any other which will be added in the future)

Comment: @jumpjack well if you're creating the context on the canvas for the first time. Your return value should generally match the first argument you gave in `getContext()`. If request `webgl2` on a device that only supports `webgl` (1) would lead to a `null` return value. If you didn't first create the context, I can't think of a way other than guess and check. But, I'm no WebGL expert. You can also check for WebGL2 support using other methods afaik.

Comment: I found this answer for "hacking" the getContext() function so as to save the selected context upon creation; it worked to figure out which context is used by CesiumJS by putting this code before any CesiumJS code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26983095/1635670  .   I also found that I can overlay another canvas with 2d context to the webgl context used by Cesium.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure javascript runs **after** the canvas HTML element

**This is bad**

```
<body>
    <script src="Canvas.js"></script>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

**This is good**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="Canvas.js"></script>'
</body>
```

This is basically how I fixed my problem

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to a different error, namely, that `getContext()` cannot be called on a null canvas element, rather than canvas element being non-null yet still returning a null from `canvas.getContext("2d")`?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and now it is resolved by using
`var canvas=document.querySelector("canvas");` instead of `var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");`.

The difference is:

`var canvas=document.querySelector("canvas");` is getting the element from tag name `canvas`.

`var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");` is getting the element from the id named `canvas`.

You can try this out.