# Set HTML canvas context via object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Up until now, I have set HTML canvas context the way in tutorials it is [shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage), like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "15px calibri";
...
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to set the context of the canvas by passing in an object with the correct attributes to one of it's methods? For example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


var context = {
    font: "15px calibri",
    ...
);

canvas.setContext(context);
```

The reason for this is I am creating a custom canvas in angular. For example, my `controller` will get the `<canvas>` element. A method in a `service` will callback the context object to set for the canvas.

The custom canvas is to be converted to PNG and set as the `icon` for a Marker on Google Maps. The marker is added to the maps in the `service`:

```
addMarkerToMap: function(position, map, canvas) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    });
}
```

So I am hoping to pass in the `canvas` element into this fucntion *(with it's context already set)* and just set it's PNG equivalent as the Marker `icon`.

**EDIT:**

I've now realised that other then just setting attributes (i.e. `fillStyle`), I am invoking the contexts methods (i.e. `beginPath()`).
I think that this will make it much harder to accomplish what I am trying

Comment: I don't understand why this requires "setting" the context object

Comment: Do you just want to be able to do a bulk-write of all the properties like `font`, `fillStyle`, etc?

Comment: @qxz no. I want to bulk-write all of the attributes into one object yes. However, because I am relying on a `service` to set the context it becomes harder. For example, I attempted to pass in the canvas element into the service and then set it's context, but because the service is not mapped with the template, it did not realise setting of the context

Answer (score 2):

Even though it looks like nonsence, after you mutate context of a canvas element, it is preserved:

```
const canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '15px Calibri';

const canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
console.log(canvas2.getContext('2d').font); // -> "15px Calibri"
```

So, in you case, it is safe to rely on context at any moment in future after you pass reference to canvas element to `addMarkerToMap` function.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293778/switch-canvas-context) answer - and the spec as it says, you possibly cannot replace the canvas context with another, as "Every canvas has what is called a primary context".

If possible, you could create a canvas programmatically and then append it to HTML as a child (or even cloning & replacing the old one at cases - if not too many replacements happening).

You could for instance use jQuery to do something like:

```
// Just a new canvas, you could even clone the old one
var canvas1 = $('<canvas/>', {
  id: 'canvas1',
  height: 500,
  width: 200,
  font: '15 px'
});
document.body.appendChild(canvas1);
```

Comment: I like this idea, will test it out and let you know

Comment: I've now realised a problem. I am drawing shapes (so using `beginPath()` etc.) and do not think it would work as they're methods on the context not just attributes

Comment: What blocks you from programmatically calling these methods to the created by jQuery canvas and then appending the new canvas into your HTML?