# Detect whether canvas already has a context

Tags: html, canvas, webgl

Is it possible, given a `canvas`, to either:

- Detect if it already has an associated `2d` or `webgl` context without calling `getContext`?
- Or when calling `getContext`, determine whether the returned context was freshly created or preexisting?

Comment: Use case: https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any public documented method to detect what context has been requested from the canvas element. The element itself is just the final bitmap and unaware of how the pixels got into it.

The only way that I am aware of is to hack the `getContext()` call to record what context was requested (or just make a plain wrapper function you call instead of the native call):

```js
// store old call
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._getContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;

// store type if requested
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._contextType = null;

// wrapper for old call allowing to register type
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(type) {
    this._contextType = type;
    return this._getContext(type);
};

// check if has context
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.hasContext = function() {
    return this._contextType;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------
//TEST:

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx;

out.innerHTML += canvas.hasContext() + '<br>';
//-> null

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

out.innerHTML += canvas.hasContext();
//-> 2d
```

```html
<output id=out></output>
<canvas id=canvas width=1 height=1></canvas>
```

You can now check if there is a context before trying to get a new one:

```
if (!canvas.hasContext()) ctx = canvas.getContext('webgl');
```

or to get the same context as before if requested, or new if not:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext(canvas.hasContext() || 'webgl');
```