# overwrite html5 canvas getContext

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, prototype, overwrite

I'm using `WebGL` and for some users, I can't get the `WebGL` context while everything indicates I should (latest Chrome version etc). My best guess so far, is that some extension calls `getContext('2d')` before I call `getContext('webgl')`, which will make my call return `null` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13406681/2054629))

So I'm trying to overwrite `getContext` to prevent calls for '2d' context:

```
const _getContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (type, options) => {
  console.log(this, arguments);

  if (type !== 'webgl' && type !== 'experimental-webgl') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error('getContext asked for type '+type+' and options '+options);
    }, 0);
    return null;
  }

  let res, error;
  try{
    // res = _getContext.apply(this, [type, options]);
    res = _getContext.apply(this, arguments);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('oups!', e);
    error = e;
    // this will be TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)
  }

  if (error)
    throw error;
  return res;
};
```

This doesn't work: when calling `canvas.getContext("webGL")` the error `TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)` is thrown (`canvas` being a Canvas DOM element) More surprisingly, `arguments` is not like `[type, options]`, but more like

```
// result from console.log(arguments);
0: require(id)
1: Object
2: Module
3: "/client/modules/video-player/VideoPlayer.jsx"
4: "/client/modules/video-player"
callee: (require,exports)
length: 5
```

I'm not sure if that's because I'm using ES2015 modules... (FYI, the context `this` is `window`. I don't know if that's expected either)

Still calling directly `_getContext.apply(this, [type, options])` instead of `_getContext.apply(this, arguments)` doesn't remove the error.

Finally working directly on the DOM element methods works just fine:

```
const _getContext = canvas.getContext.bind(canvas);
canvas.getContext = (type, options) => {
  if (type !== 'webgl' && type !== 'experimental-webgl') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error('getContext ask for type '+type+' and options '+options);
    }, 0);
    return null;
  }
  return _getContext(type, options);
};
```

But I'd rather overwrite the prototype to make sure the suspicious call doesn't get called in between the DOM element instantiation and me overwriting its `getContext` method.

Comment: This works https://github.com/benvanik/WebGL-Inspector/blob/master/core/embed.js

Comment: thanks, the issue gets fixed by changing `(type, options) => {` to `function(type, options) {` which is extremely weird and that I'll look into

Comment: thanks for posting this, which helped me isolate the issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that replacing `(type, options) => {` by `function(type, options) {` fixed the issue. I'll look more into where this surprising thing is coming from (is it a `Babel` bug? Is it my environment? Is there something I'm missing with ES2015? etc)

Comment: The issue with `=>` is it's just a shortcut for `bind` which means it's binding whatever `this` was when you created the function. In your case you need the `this` passed when the function is called. You can't do that with `=>` or `bind`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187705/what-scope-is-this-of-a-node-js-object-when-it-gets-called-at-the-top-level/49187855#49187855) which mentions arrow functions near the bottom.