# What scope is 'this' of a node.js object when it gets called at the top-level?

Tags: javascript, class, scope, this

I read ["Why and how to bind methods in your React component classes?"](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/) and grabbed the basic idea of how different is `this` by the scopes it gets called.

I made a simple class to test this.

```
class Something {
  constructor(some) {
    this.some = some;
  }

  print() {
    console.log(
      "print from ",
      this,
      this === undefined ? "!!this is undefined!!" : this.some
    );
  }
}
```

From what I understood, the scope of `this` can be different although it is from the same object (instance).

```
const some = new Something("is");
some.print(); // 'this' is defined. 'this.some' is 'is'.

const going = some.print;
going(); // 'this' is undefined.
going.call(some); // 'this' is defined. 'this.some' is 'is'.
```

But then, why is `this` (which should be the object itself) `undefined` in the latter case? Shouldn't it be the top-level `this`, which is an empty object `{}`?

Comment: How can `going.call(some);` be defined since it is coming before the const statement?

Comment: @gurvinder372 My bad. I'll edit my snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a function `print`

when you call it like this

```
some.print();
```

that effectively gets translated to this

```
print.call(some, ...args)
```

When you just pull it out

```
const going = some.print
```

You've just gotten a reference to the standalone function so calling it with

```
going()
```

Is the same as calling

```
print();
```

It's the `.` between `some` and `print` that is magically passing `some` as `this` to `print`. `going()` has no period so no this is passed.

Note that you could assign going to an object and use the period operator to do the magic "pass the thing on the left as `this`" operation

```js
function print() {
  console.log(this);
}

const someObj = {
  foo: print,
};

someObj.foo();
```

all the `class` keyword does is help assign print to `Something`'s prototype

```
class Something {
  print() { console.log(this); }
}
```

is the same as

```
function Something() {}  // the constructor
Something.prototype.print = function() { console.log(this} );
```

which is also effectively the same as this

```
function print() { console.log(this); }
function Something() {}  // the constructor
Something.prototype.print = print;
```

Saikat showed using `bind`. Bind effectively makes a new function that wraps your old function.  Example

```
const going = print.bind(foo);
```

Is nearly the same as

```
function createAFuncitonThatPassesAFixedThis(fn, objectToUseAsThis) {
  return function(...args) {
    return fn.call(objectToUseAsThis, ...args);
  }
}

const going = createAFunctionThatPassesAFixedThis(print, foo);
going();  // calls print with 'foo' as this
```

Some of the other answers have appear to have a fundamental mis-understanding of `this`. `this` is not the "owner" nor is `this` the current object. `this` is just effectively another variable inside a function. It gets set automatically if you use the `.` operator with a function call. so `a` `.` `b()` sets `this` to `a`. if the dot operator did not exist you could still set `this` by using `call` or `apply` as in `somefuntion.call(valueForThis, ...args)` or `somefunction.apply(valueForThis, [...args])`;

```js
function print() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

print.call({name: "test"});  // prints test

const foo = {
  name: "foo",
  bar: print,
};

foo.bar();  // prints foo

function Something(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Something.prototype.someFunc = print;

const s = new Something("something");
s.someFunc();  // prints something

s.foobar = print;
s.foobar();   // prints something
```

Also note that ES6 added the `=>` arrow operator which binds `this` to whatever it was when the function is created. In other words

```
const foo = () => { console.log(this); }
```

Is the same as

```
const foo = function() { console.log(this); }.bind(this);
```

it should also be clear that both functions made with `bind` and arrow functions you can not change `this` using `call` or `apply` since effectively they made a wrapper that always sets `this` to what it was when the wrapper was made just like `createAFuncitonThatPassesAFixedThis` did above.

Let's add some comments to show what I mean

```
function createAFuncitonThatPassesAFixedThis(fn, objectToUseAsThis) {

  // return a function that calls fn with objectToUsAsThis as this
  return function(...args) {

    // when we arrive here from the "going.call" line below
    // `this` will be "someObject"
    // but on the next line we're passing "objectToUseAsThis" to fn as this
    // so "someObject" is effectively ignored.

    return fn.call(objectToUseAsThis, ...args);
  }
}

const going = createAFunctionThatPassesAFixedThis(print, foo);
going.call(someObject);  // pass some object as `this`
```

One more thing. It's very common to use `bind` to make a function for an event listener or callback. It's very common in React. Example

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    // 'this' will be the current component since we bound 'this' above
    console.log("was clicked");
  }
  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</button>);
  }
}
```

This would be handled in at least 3 common ways.

1. Using `bind` in the constructor (see above)
2. Using `bind` in render

   ```
     render() {
       return (<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click me</button>);
     }
   ```
3. Using arrow functions in render

   ```
     render() {
       return (<button onClick={() => { this.handleClick(); }}>click me</button>);
     }
   ```

Above I showed what `bind` and `=>` actually do with `createAFuncitonThatPassesAFixedThis`. They create a new function. So that should make it clear that if use style 2 or 3 above when every single time `render` is called a new function is created. If you use style 1 then a new function is only created in the constructor. It's a style issue as to whether or not that's important. Creating more functions means more garbage which means a possibly slower webpage but in most cases unless you have a crazy complicated webpage that is rendering constantly it probably doesn't matter which of the 3 ways you do it.

Comment: One quick question. In order to make 'this' constant, I saw many tutorials doing `this.print = this.print.bind(this)` in constructor. (I understand what it does.) Is it a fairly common practice to do?

Comment: Yes, it's very common. It's extremely useful for assigning functions to event listeners so they will have the correct `this` for the component when the event arrives

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol - You may also want to explore how arrow functions work. Arrow functions keep a reference to their surrounding context as the value of `this`. If the `print()` method was changed to an arrow function, your code would work as you expect it to. Your question was a big part of the reason arrow functions were added. gman's answer is perfectly spot on, but I wanted to add this bit.

Comment: added a note about arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

you should correct this line to

```
const going = some.print.bind(some);
```

Otherwise going is getting a different scope and its not an member of some object so `this` is `undefined`

**NOTE**

`this` refers to the current class object. And `going` is not a member of any class so `this` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
const going = some.print;
going(); // 'this' is undefined.
```

Here, in the first line, you're storing a reference to the `print` function (property) of the `some` object in the variable `going`.

Note, you're just storing the reference to that particular property (`print`), not along with the owner (`some`).

`this` refers to the 'owner' always.

So when you execute `going`, the owner (`this`) is unknown (or call it `undefined`).