# HTML5 - Canvas available contexts

Tags: html5-canvas

How can I get a list of the available contexts on a given canvas? Unfortunately, using getContext on every possible option would not work since https://stackoverflow.com/a/13406681/2054629
So

```
var possibleContexts = ['2d', 'webgl', 'webgl2', 'experimental-webgl', 'experimental-webgl2', ...];
var availableContexts = possibleContexts.filter(function(c) { return canvas.getContext(c); });
```

won't work

I'm trying to get a better understanding while at some point in my code webgl context is available and sometime not. I have users for who a newly created canvas will have a webgl context and the one I'm interested in fails. I'm trying to better understand that. So solutions that would create new canvas won't work here...

At the moment I'm doing things like:

```
var testWebGl = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('canvas.getContext('webgl')');
};
```

and then

```
if (testWebGl())
  doSomeWebGlStuff(myCanvas);
```

And occasionally `doSomeWebGlStuff` will fails because I can't get a webgl context on `myCanvas`. So I'd like to get all the available contexts on the exact canvas I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The code won't work since you use the same canvas object for `getContext()` in all cases. The tests must be performed on different elements than the one you intend to actually use, which means you have to create a new canvas element instance before each `getContext()` as @tommie showed in his now deleted answer (running the snippet was evidence of that).

For reference, this is what tommie had in his answer with minor modifications/comments:

```
var possibleContexts = ['bitmaprenderer', '2d', 'webgl', 'webgl2', 'experimental-webgl', 'experimental-webgl2'];
var availableContexts = possibleContexts.filter(function(c) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");  // new canvas element for test only
  if (canvas.getContext(c)) {return c}
});
```

You can alternatively check for the existence of context objects directly:

```
var availableContexts = [];

if (typeof CanvasRenderingContext2D !== "undefined")
    availableContexts.push("2d");

// prefer webgl over experimental-webgl
var hasWebGL = !!document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");

if (typeof WebGLRenderingContext !== "undefined")
    availableContexts.push(hasWebGL ? "webgl" : "experimental-webgl");

...etc.
```

Adjust as needed.