# UnCaught Type Error in my draw function in Javascript (Webgl)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is the draw function I made:

```
function draw(ev, canvas){
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

And here is how it is called in my main function:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){ 
draw(ev, canvas, a_Position); 
};
```

The exact error I'm getting says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of null
```

I thought it was a problem with how I was using beginPath but when I add a line changing the stroke style for example and put it above the beginPath line I get an error about that. Any idea why my function doesn't draw lines following the mouse? This is the first program I have made in Javascript so I could be missing something obvious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not WebGL. You're using the [2D Canvas API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canvas getContext("2d") returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796194/canvas-getcontext2d-returns-null)

Comment: How would I accomplish this in WebGL?

Comment: Accomplish what? Drawing a line? [It's not exactly easy.](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard) Maybe you should first follow some basic tutorials on WebGL so you know the difference between it and the 2D API.

Comment: I am trying to click to make the start of a line and then a rubberbanding line follows the mouse and when I click it creates a line between the two points I clicked. I probably should follow some tutorials first, I didn't realize how difficult this would be. Thank you Mike.