# getting this error: Canvas01.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fillRect' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var canvas=document.querySelector('canvas'); //search all doc for canvas :)

canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2D'); //returning drwing context to c;

c.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

Canvas01.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fillRect' of null

Comment: Try `console.log(c)` before the `fillRect` call. You may find that `c` is undefined or null. Then you have to determine why. If that is the case put more information in the question so we can help you better.

Comment: i've pasted the exact error now

Comment: console.log(c) returning null

Comment: Then check [this StackOverflow question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796194/canvas-getcontext2d-returns-null)

Comment: problem solved thnx, 2D was wron it should've been 2d